# Render file from controller

Tags: grails, grails-orm, render

I'm working on a grails application and struggling with rendering text to a file. Currently I can render the text to the screen with the function below which sits in the controller:

```
    def generateTemplateSQL(Template templateInstance){

    def result = templatingService.buildTemplateSql(templateInstance)
    render result
  }
```

Now I want to be able to print the same text to a file and this is what I have below. However the button on the front end that I've created for this function causes a 404 error once pressed. I'm guessing I've got something out of place. Any ideas?

```
    def writeTemplateSQLToFile(Template templateInstance){

    def result = templatingService.buildTemplateSql(templateInstance)
    render (file: new File(result), fileName: "TemplateSQL.met", contentType: "text/met")
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "rendering text to a file"? Do you want to save the text in a file on the server side, or do you want to send the text to the browser and have the user prompted to save it in a file locally?

Comment: I want the user to be prompted to save the text to a file locally. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def writeTemplateSQLToFile(Template templateInstance){

    def result = templatingService.buildTemplateSql(templateInstance)

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=TemplateSQL.met")
    response.contentType = 'text/met'
    response.outputStream << result
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Comment: With this code I click the Write SQL To File button I created that calls writeTemplateSQLToFile from the controller which presents all of the SQL on screen. From here I can right click on the page and save the file but I'd like the user to be prompted asking if they want to save as? Is that possible?

Comment: Solved! adding attachment; like below made the file download.

response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TemplateSQL.met")

Comment: @Jamie this must be browser-dependent, because it worked for me in Firefox without `attachment;`

Comment: Perhaps, I'm running this in Chrome. Do you or anyone know how to force a prompt for a save-as dialogue window to pop-up and ask the user if they want to save the file? Currently it automatically downloads straight to the browser without confirming it with the user.

Comment: There is a browser setting that controls this. You can either tell the browser to save every downloaded file in the same folder, or prompt you for the location to save it in.

Comment: You're correct I tried this in IE and it prompted me if I wanted to save or open the file so working as intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `render (file: new File(..), fileName: "TemplateSQL.met" ...)` reads the given file from the server's file system and sends it as a response to the client. In your case the `result` variable should represent an absolute path to location on filesystem where "TemplateSQL.met" file resides.

I don't think this is your case. If you want to save the content of the result variable to the file, use [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: Ah ok I wasn't aware that it worked like that. I assumed it would be creating a new file containing result. Thanks for the clarification and I will look into FileOutputStream.